# Will ssis script component output be sorted?

Tags: ssis, pivot, script-component

I am adding rows in sequence in a script component. The sequence is such that I am parsing values from an input string then adding them to the output. This way all values from a particular input string are added before those from the next input string ( or so I assume).

Is this assumption incorrect?

I ask because I need to use the pivot transform (needs data sorted) after the script component and for performance reasons I would rather not add a sort between them.

So when I pivot on the original input string's identifier, will my pivot results be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar solution. Short answer is yes but this may depend on how you write your script task. Using the Input0Buffer buffer and calling  .[NextRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.scriptbuffer.nextrow.aspx)  and then after what ever logic / processing you do,  send the row to the one of your outputbuffers using [AddRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.scriptbuffer.addrow.aspx). The operation becomes a synchronous row by row operation.